# How to remove button "use my phone number"?

Tags: java, android, twitter-digits, google-fabric, fabric-digits

I use [Twitter-Digits library](http://get.digits.com). How to immediately go to the number input, without pressing this button in `Fragment`. I tried this option

```
AuthConfig.Builder builder = new AuthConfig.Builder();

    builder.withAuthCallBack(new AuthCallback() {
        @Override
        public void success(DigitsSession session, String phoneNumber) {
            TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Authentication successful for "
                    + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(DigitsException error) {

        }
    });

    AuthConfig autConfig = builder.build();
    Digits.authenticate(autConfig);
```

but it does not work. Can you tell me?

Comment: Kindly check your developer console. Make sure that the callback url is present

Answer (score 1):

Mike from a Fabric here, the user must click on the button in order to confirm that their number is correct and that they agree to the Digits terms of service. It can be pre-filled, but the user must click the button.

Comment: But where the button "use my number", there are no terms of service. That is, how to automatically go to the page where you need to fill out the phone number?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, currently we don't have a way to support this. Firebase Authentication is fully customizable, so I'd recommend migrating to that.

Comment: But on the site they write that in a few weeks only they will send the instruction for migration

Comment: [There](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/digits-android) wrote: `Phone number sign-in is not yet available in Firebase Authentication for Android, so migration from Digits is not yet possible. This page will be updated with migration steps when the Android SDKs become available in late May 2017.`